# Can I add a mockup image in android interface builder and lay my own layout on top of it to match the specs?

Tags: android, android-layout, interface-builder

I am new android beginner and I am working on a project. I have some questions regarding coding the UI.

When I am given mockups of the app, I don't have the font size and the margins. Our ios developer told me just to put the mockup in the interface builder and lay my own layout on top of it and fix the specs to make it perfectly match with the mockup. (He can do this in ios)

Can I do that in android studio?? If so, how?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can define your layout with FrameLayout, the first view just put your mockup picture and layout it on the top view ?